# LeakCanary reports 0 distinct leaks but often dumps hprof files

Tags: leakcanary

According to LeakCanary, my app has 0 "distinct leaks", but I find many .hprof files on the phone.  What does that mean?  I opened some of the files with leakcanary but don't see strange things (I am novice).  What should I do?